# Can't figure out how to run this script

Tags: terminal, script

I'm trying to run the following:
`% sudo hfsfuse --force -o noatime /dev/[DEVICE IDENTIFIER] /path/to/empty/folder`

I have a fusion drive on my iMac and I'm trying to access a folder called "Folder" in my Documents folder. I've updated the above script to read:

`% sudo hfsfuse --force -o noatime /dev/disk2s1 /Users/Ferris/Documents/Folder`

and this is coming up with a password prompt. I enter my password, and then Terminal gives me "could not open device
Couldn't open volume: Operation not permitted"

Thoughts? Corrections to my script? Thanks everyone. Hope you're staying safe and healthy.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with asking here, but you may find an answer more quickly in the future by using http://apple.stackexchange.com . You can search there for an answer to this issue, but please don't double-post on both sites.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possibly permissions issue on the device or filesystem inconsistency.  I would like to suggest to check **permissions** on : `/dev/disk2s1`.

Also try to run fsck :

**Terminal** :  `fsck -y /dev/disk2s1`

**GUI** : 
Go to "Disk Utility".
Head to "Applications" > "Utilities".
Or tap "Command + Space" and type Disk Utility.
Then highlight the drive and click on run.

For debugging purpose try to mount it as read-only :

```
sudo hfsfuse --force -o noatime,ro /dev/disk2s1 /Users/Ferris/Documents/Folder
```

Comment: I got back: fsck usage: fsck [-fdnypqL] [-l number]  Not sure what that means. When I go to Info on Macintosh HD, it says "You can only read" and it doesn't let me change "admin" or "everyone"'s permissions. Is that right? I have this feeling that I'm making a really simple error.

Comment: Yes, I think you cannot mount the filesystem as read write but try to mount it as read only : sudo hfsfuse --force -o noatime,ro /dev/disk2s1 /Users/Ferris/Documents/Folder

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same "Operation not permitted" message.

Comment: Check the edit i have made

Comment: What was the difference you made? Still getting the same message.

Comment: Have you tried to run filesystem check from GUI ?